# sbt assemblyは成功するのに実行するとExceptionInInitializerErrorが出る

Tags: scala, sbt

SpamFilterプロジェクト( https://github.com/lamrongol/JapaneseTwitterSpamFilter/blob/master/src/main/scala/lamrongol/twitter/spamfilter/SimpleSpamFilter.scala )で`sbt assembly`を実行すると成功しjarファイルができるのですが、それを以下のようなコマンドで実行すると、

```
java -cp .\SpamFilter-assembly-1.0.jar lamrongol.twitter.spamfilter.SimpleSpamFilter
```

以下のようなエラーが出て正常に動作しません。

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at lamrongol.twitter.spamfilter.SimpleSpamFilter.main(SimpleSpamFilter.scala)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
        at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
        at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.hasNext(BufferedSource.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:413)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
        at lamrongol.twitter.spamfilter.SimpleSpamFilter$.loadResource(SimpleSpamFilter.scala:64)
        at lamrongol.twitter.spamfilter.SimpleSpamFilter$.<init>(SimpleSpamFilter.scala:16)
        at lamrongol.twitter.spamfilter.SimpleSpamFilter$.<clinit>(SimpleSpamFilter.scala)
        ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

調べたところExceptionInInitializerErrorが出るのはclass(object)の初期化に失敗したときであり、今回はjarではjava.nio.charset.MalformedInputExceptionが起きてしまうことが原因だとわかりました。

`scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stream)`を`scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stream, "UTF-8")`と文字コードを追加することで解決しました。